# Alignment in custom description environment

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

I have to list the hardware of a computer, and I'd like to use the `description` environment from the `enumitem` package.

I have several problems of alignment as you can see on the picture.

I want the labels to be on the left margin (as they actually are), and the content to be aligned with the longest element. The last thing I want is to have the `\\` command setting the text on the same alignment (`600 GB` aligned with the `160 GB`)

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[locale = FR, binary-units, abbreviations,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

    \begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{Connectivity},
        leftmargin=\widthof{Connectivity},align=left]%2.9cm
    \item[Processor] Intel Xeon i7 64 bits 16 cœurs @\SI{2.9}{\giga\hertz}
    \item[Memory] \SI{64}{\giga\byte} RAM DDR3 @\SI{1600}{\mega\hertz}
    \item[Storage] \SI{160}{\giga\byte} : partition \texttt{boot}\\ \SI{600}{\giga\byte} : partition \texttt{home}
    \item[Connectivity] 3xUSB 3.0
    \item[Internet] 2xGigabit Ethernet
\end{description}


\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I tried setting the `\labelwidth` of the longest word (Connectivity), but it fails because

- Content is not aligned:  `3xUSB` is not in the same vertical as the rest(`Intel`)
- The second line of `Storage` doesn't start at the same point as the first line

[image: MWE Result]

Any ideas on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: For the width problem, you  can try `\widthof{\textbf{Connectivity}}` since the word *connectivity* is in bold and has a bigger width than non-bold *connectivity*

Answer (score 5):

Since the left hand column of the `description` is in bold letters, you have to calculate the the width based on bold letters. Trying `\widthof{\textbf{Connectivity}}` solves that problem.

As for the insufficient indenting when multiple lines are present, they seem to be about one `n` space and so I gave a dummy character `n` or `y` to the argument of the second `widthof` command and it **seems** to work. This may not be the *right way* to solve the second problem though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[locale = FR, binary-units, abbreviations,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

    \begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{\textbf{Connectivity}},
        leftmargin=\widthof{\textbf{Connectivityy}},align=left]%2.9cm
    \item[Processor] Intel Xeon i7 64 bits 16 cœurs @\SI{2.9}{\giga\hertz} \lipsum[1]
    \item[Memory] \SI{64}{\giga\byte} RAM DDR3 @\SI{1600}{\mega\hertz}
    \item[Storage] \SI{160}{\giga\byte} : partition \texttt{boot}\\ \SI{600}{\giga\byte} : partition \texttt{home}
    \item[Connectivity] 3xUSB 3.0
    \item[Internet] 2xGigabit Ethernet
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: widthof and description commands]

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work perfectly. I have another `\description` with other labels, and it does the trick :)

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you mean by "gave a dummy character" as I can't see it in your example. I don't have any labels that are longer than the standard indent but the first line starts before the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: There is an additional 'y' in `\widthof{\textbf{Connectivityy}}`